# question editing why users approve these type editing in questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Last two days I found some edits which is made by the user:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/68824/vrajesh-patel

https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/304624/revisions
https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/304626/revisions
https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/304670/revisions
https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/304623/revisions

why some users approved it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revision is good.

Don't find any issue on this those above edit. Some styling and spell correction happens on the above edits which is useful for the question which helps for understanding.

The user has edit privileges, so he can edit.   https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Also, community people view his edits, get approved.

Comment: I had the same issue with that user . He trying to hunt down the reputations just by adjusting space and all . Came here to  point out that guy and  found this